# SVG inside bootstrap(4.3) popover not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg, bootstrap-4, popover, popper.js

I'm trying to show a **svg** icon inside a bootstrap `popover`. But it doesn't work. Though images are working fine. Why it's not working and how to make it work?

Here's my HTML:

```
<a tabindex="0"
class="small mx-3 content-popover"
data-toggle="popover"
data-html="true"
data-placement="bottom"
data-trigger="focus"
title="SVG inside popup"
data-content='
<svg width="50" height="50"><circle r="20" cx="25" cy="25" style="fill: blue"/></svg>'>POPUP</a>
```